# Query for Joining Two Tables With Possible Multiple Mapping

Tags: sql

First_table

```
srno  wono   Actual_Start_Date  Actual_End_Date
1      31     2012-06-02         2012-06-05
2      32     2012-06-05         2012-06-22
3      33     2012-06-11         2012-06-23
4      34     2012-06-23         2012-06-30
5      A-2    2012-06-24         2012-06-25
6      BU     2012-06-24         2012-06-26
7      40     2012-06-25         2012-06-27
```

second_table

```
srno  wono    Base_start_date     Base_end_date    uploadhistoryid
1     31       2012-06-05            2012-06-05           1
2     32       2012-06-11            2012-06-12           2
3     32       2012-06-15            2012-06-17           3
4     32       2012-06-18            2012-06-20           4
5     33       2012-06-22            2012-06-25           5
5     33       2012-06-23            2012-06-25           5
```

Result Required

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Reports_Subanalysis]
(
@WONo VARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT   
          'SAT' AS stage,
                   s.Base_start_date   AS start_date,
                   s.Base_end_date   AS  end_date,
                   f.Actual_Start_Date   AS Actual_Start_Date,
                   f.Actual_end_Date   AS Actual_End_Date
                   FROM First_table f,
                   second_table B
                   WHERE A.wOno=B.nOno
                   AND f.uploadhistoryid in (SELECT min(uploadhistoryid) FROM second_table C WHERE f.wono = C.wono)
                   AND b.wono=@WONo

END
```

when I pass '32'

Result

```
stage    start_date     end_date      Actual_Start_Date   Actual_End_Date

SAT      2012-06-11     2012-06-12      2012-06-05          2012-06-05
```

how Can I get the result like this when I pass non matching value like 'BU'

```
stage    start_date     end_date      Actual_Start_Date   Actual_End_Date
SAT       NULL           NULL         2012-06-24           2012-06-26
```

What modification do I need in my routine?

Comment: Ah, another "how to do a join" question. These must make up about 10% of all questions on SO. Try http://howtodoajoin.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Ben: That link doesn't open. (Or, more precisely, it says, ‘Couldn't find howtodoajoin.stackexchange.com’)

Comment: @AndriyM, no but it *ought* to exist...

Answer (score 0):

you will need to join second table using left join. Also use -  **f**.wono=@WONo

```
SELECT TOP 1             
 'SAT' AS stage,                    
  s.Base_start_date   AS start_date,                    
  s.Base_end_date   AS  end_date,                    
  f.Actual_Start_Date   AS Actual_Start_Date,                    
  f.Actual_end_Date   AS Actual_End_Date                    
FROM First_table f                    
LEFT JOIN second_table s ON f.wOno=s.nOno
WHERE
f.wono=@WONo 
ORDER BY s.uploadhistoryid ASC
```

Comment: This left join is  not working here .. even if there is no matching wono for 'BU' in the second table, how to handle b.uploadhistoryid which is not there in the second table

Comment: ur query alias are very unclear which u need to fix. I have removed ur inner query part and replaced with limit and order by. see updated query above

Comment: @ Kshitij Just updated the query with right allias please check. I need the desired result while passing 'BU' as mentioned above.

Comment: ur aliases are still not proper....where is alias `A` pointing to? do you `f.uploadhistoryid` in your first table? which DB are you using? have you checked my updated query?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
       'SAT' AS stage,
        s.Base_start_date AS start_date,
        s.Base_end_date AS end_date,
        f.Actual_Start_Date AS Actual_Start_Date,
        f.Actual_end_Date AS Actual_End_Date
FROM First_table f
LEFT JOIN second_table s
WHERE f.wOno=s.nOno
  AND s.uploadhistoryid in (SELECT min(uploadhistoryid) FROM second_table s2 WHERE s2.wono = s.wono)
  AND f.wono=@WONo --please take this one..I do not have f.uploadhistoryid in first table. I am using sql server. ur query does not work..thanks

Comment: since u are using Sql Server u will need to use `TOP 1` ...see my updated answer above

Comment: Still having some problem matching records are now troubling me.